# Laravel 5.7 gRPC Integration

Tags: php, laravel-5, grpc

I have setup gRPC in core PHP and it is working fine but I want to use it with laravel 5.7. I have downloaded gRPC using `composer.json`. Now I don't know what I have to do for using gRPC in it.

I have added below in my composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "datto/protobuf-php": "dev-master",
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.15.0"
    },
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/stanley-cheung/Protobuf-PHP"
        }
    ]
```

But now I am not getting what should be next to do. So anyone knows then please let me know. I have my core PHP code for gRPC(core library example) which I have setup from this web url. [gRPC in PHP](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php.html). So I just want to integrate into laravel.

Answer (score 5):

**How to use protoc generated files with Laravel (5.7)**

- Prepare your .proto file describing your services as you would normally do
- Set as package name `package app.grpc;`
- Run the generation command: `protoc --php_out=./  --grpc_out=./  --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/your/path/to/grpc_php_plugin yourfile.proto`
- Now copy App/Grpc inside laravel App
- Copy GPBMetadata folder as new folder in laravel root
- Change `composer.json` file inserting `GPBMetadata` location in the autoload classmap section (*see below*)
- Run command `composer dump-autoload`
- Now you can use your generated classes in any controller, remember to add `use App\Grpc\YourClassName` at the top.

let me know if someone have better solutions to this

### Relevant part of `composer.json`:

```
...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "GPBMetadata"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: What is the "grpc_php_plugin" plugin? I followed the instructions here: https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php/ but it always says: "protoc-gen-php: program not found or is not executable
--php_out: protoc-gen-php: Plugin failed with status code 1."

Comment: @JohnMellor the plugin is required to generate php files from proto files. it has to be build separately via the steps here https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/#php-protoc-plugin

i had to install the following dependencies (automake, libtool, autoconf, build-essential, shtool) in order to build the plugin though.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need these anymore

```
"datto/protobuf-php": "dev-master",

"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/stanley-cheung/Protobuf-PHP"
        }
    ]
```

Instead, you should add `"google/protobuf": "^3.6.1"` to your `require`.

See this as an example:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/php/composer.json

The versions were out-of-date - just take the latest releases.

Comment: I have replaced `datto/protobuf-php` to `google/protobuf": "^3.6.1`. But i don't know what should i do configure gRPC in laravel.

Comment: after adding this line "google/protobuf": "^3.6.1"  any errors you got while installing dependency ?